# Filter data using lodash

Tags: lodash

How can filter the data with some inner attribute value.

```
updated_id='1234';

var  result= _.map(self.list, function (item) {
                     // return only item.User_Info.id=updated_id
                    });
```

Comment: var result = _.filter(self.list, function(item) {
  return only item.User_Info.id === updated_id;
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lodash#matchesProperty`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#matchesProperty) variant of [`lodash#filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) to filter out objects that you need using the path of the property. The variant is in the 3rd example of the [`lodash#filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) documentation.

```
var result = _.filter(self.list, ['User_Info.id', updated_id]);
```

```js
var self = {
  list: [
    { User_Info: { id: '4321' } },
    { User_Info: { id: '4321' } },
    { User_Info: { id: '1234' } },
    { User_Info: { id: '3214' } },
    { User_Info: { id: '2143' } }
  ]
};
var updated_id = '1234';

var result = _.filter(self.list, ['User_Info.id', updated_id]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

lodash has a filter method:

```
const updated_id='1234';

const result= _.filter(self.list, item => item.User_Info.id === updated_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash _.filter method:

```
_.filter(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
```

Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

with predicate as custom function

```
 _.filter(myArr, function(o) { 
    return o.name == 'john'; 
 });
```

with predicate as part of filtered object (the _.matches iteratee shorthand)

```
_.filter(myArr, {name: 'john'});
```

with predicate as [key, value] array (the _.matchesProperty iteratee shorthand.)

```
_.filter(myArr, ['name', 'John']);
```